# Need help finding an obscure 80's/90's scifi cartoon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have this image of a clip from a cartoon from when I was a kid that I can not find online.

What I remember is a regiment of highlanders (the military type not the immortal kind) coming over a hill with bagpipes but instead of rifles, they had lasers. I also remember it was a WWI style cartoon but with lasers and swords.

Comment: So not [Highlander: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander:_The_Animated_Series) then? Cause it does sounds a lot like it.

Comment: Can you post the image you have?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I fear the OP might mean "this image in my head"...